# Woocommerce variation image src showing small thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I updated Woocommerce to the latest version and where i was using showing variation images in my template, they had all disappeared. Looks like they've decided to drop `$variation['image_src'].`

I did some research and apparently you need to use `$variation['image']['thumb_src']`.

Frustratingly this doesn't show the variation image at full size. Does anyone know how to do this please?

I've tried `$variation['image']['large_src']` but doesn't work :(

Annoying how I can't find any instructions from Woocommerce!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$variation['image']['full_src']`

So `full_src` instead of `large_src`.